# How to add the current iteration's value to the previous iteration's value in a loop

Tags: java, loops, addition

```
public class Recount {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        boolean s = false;
        int a;
        Scanner quest = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            int n = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
            System.out.println(n);
            System.out.println("Try again?");
            s = quest.nextBoolean();
        } while (s != false);
    }
}
```

I want to add the number that was given in the previous iteration to the number in the current iteration of the loop.

Basically I want new n to be equal to old random number + new random number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the loop:

```
int n;
do {
    n += rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    System.out.println(n);
    System.out.println("Try again?");
    s = quest.nextBoolean();
} while (s != false);
```

`n` is declared outside the loop now, and the `n+=rand.nextInt(100)+1` means that we're taking that random, and adding it to `n`.

Edit to see each number:

```
int n;
do {
    int tmp;
    tmp = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    n += tmp;
    System.out.println(tmp+" Total: "+n);
    System.out.println("Try again?");
    s = quest.nextBoolean();
} while (s != false);
```

Comment: Jesus that was so easy, I can't believe I couldn't figure it out. Thanks man, you're a star.

Comment: @MadsRosenmeyer No problem. Just hit the checkmark to the left of my answer if it helped. The key here is that the variable's scope is inside the loop.

Comment: I did, but then there was some 10 minute thing.

A quick follow up question if you have time. Now that I have this, I need to make it out as if it is 2 dice that are being added together, but I need to be able to see the 2 dice rolls, for each one, but still adding on to the previous one, so for example the first roll would be 3 and 4 and the next would be 2 and 2 making the total 5 and 6, but I would still need the ability to see the 2 and the 2, is there a way to do this, using this loop?

Comment: @MadsRosenmeyer Let me just edit it for that comment, give me a mibute. Edit: Edit's in place.

Comment: Thank's. You're a star!

Answer (score 0):

```
int temp = n;
int n = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
n += temp;
```